# Nvidia Driver install - this computer is not compatible

Tags: windows, drivers, nvidia-geforce, nvidia

I'm trying to install an older version of Nvidia Driver(451.67) dated to 2020.7.9 on my computer. It's 64 bit driver and my system is also 64 bit. When trying to install, it prompts 'The system is not compatible' error. My Windows version is Version 22H2 19045.3570 Build. This started to happen after I updated my Windows one month ago. Before that, I was able to install older drivers. Now I can't even install the driver that is on the computer's driver page (Asus ROG gl553v).

Is this related to the latest Windows version? Does the latest update make the older versions of Nvidia driver obsolote?

By the way, I brought my computer to a specialist and he somehow managed to install an older version - so I know that it's possible.

I need the older version because I'm having nvllddmkm.sys error with the latest version of the driver...

If you happen to know any solution to nvlddmkm.sys error as well, it would work too.

Comment: If your "specialist" was a competent professional he or she would have reinstalled the current Windows build *from scratch* and then install all the required drivers including Nvidia's recommend one for your hardware and Windows build. That would've avoided any error unless there's an underlying hardware issue (a competent professional would troubleshoot that as well. Everything you described here is so wrong...

Comment: Well, I didn't pay him, he just installed a version and I tried it later and saw that it's working. Than I needed to update my driver and the problem got back. And now I'm unable to rollback. If somebody knows an issue about the latest update of Windows causing trouble with older versions of Nvidia drivers, maybe they can help.

Comment: I said that what you described here is the wrong approach to the issue looking at it from any angle. If it was a friend doing you a favor take it, say thanks and move on. About competency, again, everybody here with any experience disagrees, period. How to handle the problem is already "answered" at least in broad terms in the first comment. If you insist in an answer for what you think is a solution then you're falling into this trap: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem

Comment: I deleted that comment. Never mind that, sorry about it. I solved the issue by restarting the computer after uninstalling the old driver and then install the new.

Comment: The point, again, is a Windows feature update may no longer support obsolete nvidia drivers like the version you insist on installing. It probably needs a CLEAN installation of the currently recommended version for your OS and nvidia chipset model, that you obtain from Nvidia, not the vendor. And if a CLEAN installation of the correct version still fails than the problem is likely Windows itself. If you google "nvllddmkm.sys" you'll find lots of suggestions.

Answer (score 0):

I solved the issue by restarting my computer after uninstalling the existing driver and then installing the desired one.